# CSS3 Flex: Pull child to the right

Tags: html, css

here's what I have  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mWZK4/1/)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  padding: 15px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

#item-1 {
  height: 50px;
}

#item-2 {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="item-1">Home</li>
  <li id="item-2">Menu</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Settings</li>
</ul>
```

**I want the last item inside the flex-box to be pulled to the right** ("Settings" in my fiddle) while keeping all other items the way they are. The "Settings"-item should also be centered vertically and everything.

`align-self: flex-end` pushes the item to the bottom (I want it on the right).

I would very much prefer a solution using flex-box because my items have variable heights and should always be centered vertically.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 265, accepted):

Simple fix, use an auto-adjusting margin:

```
ul li:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

You may also want to not use `width: 100%` so that the element stays inside the visible area:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwLHE/

See also https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins